# Is this wiring diagram for a series of outlets correct?

Tags: wiring

NOTE: There should be a hot/black wire going from source wire to the lower connector on the switch.

The 3 outlets are going into a 3 gang box.  The 3rd outlet (the one on the far right) will be controlled via the switch to the right (the switch is located on the same wall a few feet away).

I understand different areas have different code, but in general, will this work?

[image]

Comment: No offense, but if you made that wiring setup, you may want to hire someone to do it for you. Nothing wrong with learning, but until you've learned, for safety have someone more experienced do the task. Electricity can be dangerous.

Comment: It appears to be correct (assuming the outlet contacts are bussed on both sides), but it's confusing as hell.

Comment: Well the drawing worries an awful lot about getting the wires to each *side* of the receptacle.   I just don't care, in drawings, that is.

Answer (score 9):

Your drawing is confusing and you have no power going TO the switch.

Also you showed no grounding to the receptacle boxes.

Use three core to the switch and cap of the extra white wire for future needs.

[image]

Comment: NOTE: There should be a hot/black wire going from source wire to the lower connector on the switch.

Comment: Might be worth adding details of where there will be pigtailed hot-hot and neutral-neutral connections in the last outlet box / switch box (there are a couple of different options). Assuming the OP is using 2-conductor NM between each box.

Comment: @CactusCake I don't think he needs any pig-tails if he daisy chains through the receptacles.

Comment: @Trevor Oh, I suppose not. I was thinking how there are two blacks going to the switch and no whites, but you can just as easily tape black on the ends of the white conductor, so never mind! That said, if there is thought to ever have use a "smart" switch and/or continue daisy chaining from the switch box onward at some point in the future it would be nice to have a neutral out there.

Comment: @CactusCake yup that's why I changed the image to show three core to the switch, and fed back on the red as indicated. You are tight, you  never know when you might need to carry on.

Comment: @Trevor Hmm, still not sure how you're getting the hot directly from the second outlet to the switch without pigtailing somewhere. I added an alternate version, keep the upvote though :)

Comment: @CactusCake hot goes from the second outlet out to the switch through one 3-core cable. Your solution requires two cables to run to the switch box. It also works though.

Comment: @CactusCake remember, the three receptacles are in one box.

Comment: @Trevor ah crap, I didn't notice "3 gang box" in the question, hahaha! Well, I'll leave mine up as an alternative for single gang boxes.

Comment: @Trevor Daisy chaining, especially neutrals, through the receptacle is not allowed by some electrical codes (and for good reason).

Comment: @J... Yes I'd imagine. Though it's probably more reliable than pig-tailing in this instance. Especially if you use the screw terminals, not those  push in things in the back.

Answer (score 6):

Trevor's answer is correct for a single three gang box, as the question asks.

If you have separate outlet boxes or don't have 3-core cable to hand, this is an alternative:

[image]

If you ever changed your mind about the switched outlet you could twist together the two hot conductors in the switch box and pigtail off of them to repurpose that switch for something else (bringing in more 2-core to go out to whatever new thing you want switched).